# Python3: sort of a list of tuples by first element in reverse -> if that is the same, by second element in alphabetic order

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
[(51, 'Elijah'), (144, 'Chloe'), (485, 'Elizabeth'), (485, 'Matthew'), (207, 'Natalie'), (390, 'Jayden')]
```

I want to sort it in reverse order using as the key the first element of the tuple. If that is the same, I need to sort it by the second element in alphabetical order. I tried to using sorted(lista, key=function) but i get all kind of errors. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I get 'TypeError: sort_score() missing 1 required positional argument:'. I try to use a sorting function with two arguments so I can have what to compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `reversed` option is "global", not per element of the tuple, but your first element is a number, you can reverse the numbers sorting direction by simply negating it:

```
>>> sorted(lista, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
[(485, 'Elizabeth'), (485, 'Matthew'), (390, 'Jayden'), (207, 'Natalie'), (144, 'Chloe'), (51, 'Elijah')]
```

When lists of tuples are sorted, first the first element is compared, and if it's equal the second, and so on. So as a key function you can simply create one on the fly (using `lambda`) that creates a tuple from the original tuple, but inverts the first element.

Comment: Wow. It really worked. Thank you. I was looking for a complicated answer with a costum sorting function. But I guess I'll learn how to that an other time.

Comment: This does use a custom sorting function, I just use a lambda expression to write it. You could have defined that function outside the call to sorted and then done `key=myfun` or something like that. `lambda x: (-x[0], x[1])` is equivalent to the function `def myfun(x): return (-x[0], x[1])`.